# filter sharepoint 2007 search results by date range? 

Tags: 2007, search, filter

i want to filter the sharepoint2007 search results by given date range.

I.e., 
With in a day
With in a week
With in a month
With in a year

Is it possible? If so, please help.

Comment: We could specify the date range in the advanced search page, is there a similar way to explicitly mention the date range in the search query? like modified:">01/10/2010"...

Comment: I do have a managed property in SSP of type dateandtime, is it possible to use that property in the sharepoint query ?

Comment: The query string +Created:"01/03/2011" returns the specific day result however is there a way to supply a date range?

Comment: Karthikeyan: Flagging a post for moderator attention will not get you a faster response. This is an all-volunteer community site, so you'll just have to wait for an answer along with the rest of us!

Comment: Understood, Apologies.

Comment: i do not see any direct way of doing this however there is indirect way, you have to create a timer job to calculate and update the date range against each item and corresponding metadata can be used for sharepoint search. I know, this is not the proper way however maybe used ln some situations.

Answer (score 1):

I've used methods described in [this article](http://www.philwicklund.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=7379e84f-d131-4c1b-903e-4b12849edf5b&ID=83&Web=8de7cf99-762e-4745-b902-b821d850c07f) along with date filter web parts (MOSS Enterprise) to create custom search solutions.  Since the search results is just an XSLT dataview, you can style it as needed and include additional functionality like that.